# Ffmpeg "-c copy" alternatives for fast video cutting

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to cut sections out of a video. I was using this command, as I'd done with previous videos:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:30 -c copy -y output.mp4
```

However, when I use this, depending on the time, either the first 5 seconds or last 5 seconds of video are blank.
I resorted to removing the copy command and just using:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:30 -y output.mp4
```

This worked correctly, but is much slower. Is there any fast alternative that will not corrupt the video?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. Copy is fast because to copies entire groups of frames. A group of frames (GOP) can not be split up. If you want to copy frames from a GOP, but not the entire GOP, you must reencode. Which is slower.

Comment: Copying starts at the start of a GOP but the entire GOP need not be copied.

Comment: Depending if you are trimming the beginning of the GOP or the end of the GOP, and the existence of B frames.

Comment: Thanks!! Does this mean it would be possible to achieve the speed of copy without losing some of the video by copying only part of the GOP? Or is this only possible if the start of my desired clip happens to also be the start of the GOP?

Also, I previously was working on a similar project, with videos recorded in a different manner (also mp4), but never had this problem. Do certain types of encoding not have this problem?